# Crystal report formula for time schedule based on day of week from the starting date

Tags: date, crystal-reports, formula

I have several different work hrs schedules. They each start at a different date. meaning the first monday for one schedule is different to the other schedules in any given month. For example 1st monday on schedule "A" will the second monday in a month while schedule "B" 1st monday is the 3rd monday of the month. The following month for schedule "A" 1st monday will be the 3rd monday of the month and schedule "B" will be the 4th monday of the month. it changes month by month. 
There is a start date for each schedule to use when it will be the start of that scheudle 1st Monday -Sunday and then 2nd Monday - Sunday etc. weeks for each month the 1st monday will change as it continues the pattern. 
exmaple:

Schedule A (Start date 6/15/15): 1st Sun - 0hrs (7/12/15), 1st Monday (6/15/15)- 8hrs, 1st Tue (6/16/15)- 8hrs, 1st Wed (6/17/15)- 8hrs, etc
2nd Sun (6/21/15)- 0 hrs, 2nd Monday (6/22/15)- 9 hrs, 2nd Tue (6/23/15)- 12 hrs, 2nd Wed (6/24/15)- 6 hrs, etc
3rd Sun (6/28/15)- 4 hrs, 3rd Monday (6/29/15)- 12 hrs 3rd Tues (6/30/15)- 0 hrs, 3rd Wed (7/1/15)- 0 hrs etc.

Schedule B (Start date 6/22/15): 1st Sun (7/19/15)- 12hrs, 1st Monday (6/22/15)- 4hrs, 1st Tue (6/23/15)- 0hrs, 1st Wed (6/24/15)- 0hrs, etc
2nd Sun (6/28/15)- 0 hrs, 2nd Monday (6/29/15)- 8 hrs, 2nd Tue (6/30/15)- 8 hrs, 2nd Wed (7/1/15)- 8 hrs, etc
3rd Sun (7/12/15)- 4 hrs, 3rd Monday (7/13/15)- 9 hrs 3rd Tues (7/14/15)- 9 hrs, 3rd Wed (7/15/15)- 9 hrs etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, I didnt understand a single line in there. You can really help yourself by tidying up your question and putting it in tabular format and/or image.\

Comment: you didn't explain what you need... you just wrote what yyou have... explain what you want to do with this data?